# jQuery CSS chaining background image and z-index

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, z-index, jquery-chaining

[image]

I have a div where an image is generated`.result`. I need to set a background image within that div that will act as a layer on top of the generated image. I have the following, but can't get the image to show:

```
image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result").css("background-image", "url('iphone_5.jpg') no-repeat").css("z-index", "1000"));
});
```

The image on the right in the screenshot is the rendered crop. You can see the image in the background(along the top and left border) that should sit on top of the rendered image.

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase the actual question, it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve. Also there are a few mistakes in your code! But first go for a clearer question!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the shorthand `background` syntax with the `background-image` property. You need to change that to `background`.

```
image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result").css("background", "url('iphone_5.jpg') no-repeat").css("z-index", "1000"));
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. However, I can't get the iphone image to sit on top of the generated image.

Comment: That's because it is a background image. Backgrounds go behind the content, not on top of it.

Comment: And, I'm having an early morning Friday moment here :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

```
body {
    background-image: url("gradient_bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

or

```
body {
    background: url("gradient_bg.png") no-repeat;
}
```

like

```
image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result").css("background", "url('iphone_5.jpg') no-repeat").css("z-index", "1000"));
});
```

or

```
image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result").css("background-image", "url('iphone_5.jpg')").css("Background-repeat", "no-repeat").css("z-index", "1000"));
});
```

ahh to slow :c